# 404 on dl.google.com for stable Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

​​Part of my build pipeline is to download a specific version of Chrome (google-chrome-stable_81.0.4044.138-1_amd64.deb). My local build and automated build on GitHub are both suddenly failing due to the following error:

```
Step 26/30 : RUN wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/chrome.deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_${CHROME_VERSION}_amd64.deb
560 ---> Running in 718393c11bc4
561http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_81.0.4044.138-1_amd64.deb:
5622022-01-18 08:20:09 ERROR 404: Not Found.
563The command '/bin/sh -c wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/chrome.deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_${CHROME_VERSION}_amd64.deb && apt-get update && apt-get install -y /tmp/chrome.deb --no-install-recommends --allow-downgrades fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf && rm /tmp/chrome.deb' returned a non-zero code: 8
```

I’ve had zero issue with this part of the build for months and suddenly it’s falling over. Any idea what’s going on?

Also is there a workaround whilst this gets sorted out?

Comment: I am having the same issue. It looks like this has been phased out according to this comment: http://www.hardkoded.com/blog/puppeteer-sharp-docker#comment-5679140970

Comment: Google phased out the endpoint to download Chrome? Did you manage to find a workaround?

Comment: Same here. This seems to get a fresh version of Chrome for now. `wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

Answer (score 0):

Seems that unfortunately Google is no longer providing these binaries at `http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/`.

But you can find these mirrored at `https://mirror.cs.uchicago.edu/google-chrome/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/`.